# Blackberry-ListField with images from URL (XML DATA)

Tags: xml-parsing, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, listfield

I want to display the images which are in my XML in a ListField.I have parsed the data but not able to display that data in listfield.i have created one bean class which includes setter and getter of my data.

```
 if(tempList.item(j).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("bsub")){
            tempNode = tempList.item(j);
            tempNode2 = ((NodeList)tempNode.getChildNodes()).item(0);
                            bean.setsubTitle(tempNode2.getNodeValue().trim());
                            bean.getsubTitle();
                            System.out.println("Node Value or subtitle" + bean.getsubTitle().toString());
                        }
                        if(tempList.item(j).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("bimage")){
                            tempNode = tempList.item(j);    
                            tempNode2 = ((NodeList)tempNode.getChildNodes()).item(0);
                            bean.setImageurl(tempNode2.getNodeValue().trim());
                            bean.getimageurl();
                            System.out.println("Node Value or bimg" + bean.getimageurl().toString());
                        }
```

then i have created one TableRowManager.then i added my bitmap and label in that Manager as above.

```
enter code here

        { 
    TableRowManager row = new TableRowManager(); 

    BitmapField bitmap = new BitmapField(bean.getImage());
    row.add(bitmap);
    LabelField label = new LabelField(bean.getTitle());
    row.add(label);
    label.setFont(myFont1); 
            bitmap.setFont(myFont);
```

I am getting the blank screen while running my app.
  Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

looks difficult to understand the problem with the sample code provided. Try to give the complete code. also, visit this link which demonstrates the blackberry web bitmap field. [blackberry-webbitmapfield](http://www.coderholic.com/blackberry-webbitmapfield/) which downloads image from server and renders on screen.

Comment: tableRowManager is my custom manager which is use for listview approach.